# Chrome Content-Security-Policy to load local script

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I'm currently developing an app that needs to load a local javascript file, which i can't move to the server side.

I'd like to allow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Mypath/my_local_file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="server_script/remote_file.js"></script>
```

As suggested in other questions, i've changed the content-security-policy to: default-src 'self' filesystem

But still getting 'Not allowed to load local resource'